# Make iostreams more strict

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make iostreams more strict about boolean values with some flag?

I got unexpected result using `std::boolalpha`

```cpp
bool var;
std::istringstream is("true1");
is >> std::boolalpha >> var;
```

yields `var == true`, `is.good() == 1` and `is.peek() == '1'`, when I expect `is.good() == 0`.

Similar behavior when there is no boolalpha specified:

```cpp
bool var;
std::istringstream is("1qwe");
is >> var;
```

yields `var == true`, `is.good() == 1` and `is.peek() == 'q'`, when I expect `is.good() == 0`.

Comment: It's not that iostream should be more strict, it's the _you_, as the programmer, should write code that strictly does what you want. If you want `1qwe` to fail when reading, then you should write logic for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to make iostreams more strict in this way.

There is no need either. Simply use `is.peek()` for example to check whether the entire input was consumed or not. If not, then treat the input as bad, and retry (or whatever you wanted to do in case `is.good() == 0`).

Answer (score 2):

All the formatted input functions stop after successfully reading an item and set their position just after the end of that item (on the next character).

You could just test that `peek` returns Traits::eof():

```
if (is.peek() != std::istringstream::traits_type::eof()) {
    // invalid input
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't make the stream more strict, but you can define a wrapping class that streams more "strictly".
Something along these lines (with reservations about the correctness of the stream state management):

```
template<typename T>
class stricter_io
{
public:
    explicit stricter_io(T& t) : t(t) {}

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, stricter_io<T>&& val)
    {
        auto pos = is.tellg();
        if (is >> val.t)
        {
            // Whatever condition you want; 
            // this examples requires either eof or whitespace after the item.
            auto next = is.peek();
            if (next != std::istringstream::traits_type::eof()
                && !std::isspace(next))
            {
                // Rewind the stream and enter the failure state.
                is.seekg(pos);
                is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
            }
        }
        return is;
    }

private:
    T& t;
};


int main()
{
    bool var;
    std::istringstream is("true1");
    if (is >> std::boolalpha >> stricter_io(var))
    {
        std::cout << "Good";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Bad\n";
        is.clear();
        std::string s;
        is >> s;
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
}
```